# How to handle padding errors in pkcs11?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, pkcs#11, padding-oracle-attack

I'm wondering how `C_DecryptFinal` & `C_Decrypt` are supposed to deal with padding errors.

According to [pkcs11 2.20](http://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/STANDARD/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf), `C_DecryptFinal` can return `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID` or `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_LEN_RANGE`, 
so I suppose that if padding is invalid, `C_DecryptFinal`/`C_Decrypt` return `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID`.

Is it correct?

If so, is `C_DecryptFinal`/`C_Decrypt` vulnerable to padding-oracle attacks?

Comment: I remember something vaguely about pading-oracle attacks on some particular hardware devices (or maybe their PKCS11 drivers). You need to ask google about this, but I am sure that you *will* find something related to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Citing the standard (section 11.1.6):

> - CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_LEN_RANGE: The ciphertext input to a decryption 
>     operation has been determined to be invalid ciphertext solely on the
>     basis of its length.  Depending on the operation’s mechanism, this
>     could mean that the ciphertext is too short, too long, or is not a
>     multiple of some particular blocksize.  This return value has higher
>     priority than CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID.
> - CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID: The encrypted input to a decryption
>     operation has been determined to be invalid ciphertext.  This return
>     value has lower priority than CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_LEN_RANGE.

So for block ciphers the `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_LEN_RANGE` should be returned when the input is not block-aligned.

If the input is block-aligned, the `CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID` is probably returned in case of wrong padding for the `CKM_*_PAD` mechanisms.

Thus the padding oracle attack is probably possible.

---

As the *PKCS#7* padding is the only defined padding scheme for block ciphers, it is quite often the responsibility of the application to handle the padding, which leads to what I think should be the answer to your question:

- It is up to the application (i.e. "the cryptoki client") not to provide an external attacker (i.e. the "the application client") with any oracle to determine the padding was wrong, regardless of the source of this information (i.e. the cryptoki or the application itself).
- It is probably meaningless to protect against the padding oracle attack on the cryptoki interface level (i.e. an attacker inside the application), as such an attacker can decrypt anything at will directly using the appropriate functions.

---

(Of course it is better to use some form of [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) and do not need to worry about the padding oracle attack at all)

Desclaimer: I am no crypto expert, so please do validate my thoughts.

Comment: Thx for your answer, indeed  CKR_DATA_INVALID seems to be to most appropriate error to return when an invalid padding is detected.

Comment: @klook It might be interesting to write a POC code to perform the padding oracle attack against some pkcs11 implementation (or adopt an existing one to pkcs11), but as I tried to express in the answer -- this padding oracle should be available only to the application (i.e. the "cryptoki client", who is already authorized to decrypt directly) so there is nothing to gain by using this type of attack (by the application). And it is the application responsibility not to allow an external attacker (i.e. the "application client") to gain access to the padding oracle. Does this answer your question?

Comment: According to https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/417.pdf the best solution to avoid padding oracle issues is to use an authenticated cipher-mode such as GCM so i think CKR_DATA_INVALID can be used without second thought.

Comment: @klook edited the answer in line with the previous comment.

Comment: @klook That is correct and is mentioned in the answer. What do you mean by the CKR_DATA_INVALID can be used without second thought? That you can provide the application client with this error code if authenticated encryption is used?

Comment: @klook The paper mentioned is about using the padding oracle attack to extract a value of a wrapped key and is about `C_UnwrapKey` function and not `C_DecryptFinal`/`C_Decrypt`. If an attacker had access to `C_Decrypt` for a key used to wrap any other key it is trivial to get the wrapped key value.

Comment: Regarding the attacks described in the paper, there are vendor specific solutions, e.g. SafeNet's `CKA_IMPORT` which can be used to force `CKM_WRAPKEY_[DES3/AES]_CBC` mechanism (which uses authentication) for `C_Unwrap`.

Comment: what i meant is that as long as you use an authenticated mode, returning CKR_DATA_INVALID is not an issue because an attacker won't be able to mount a chosen-cipher attack.

Comment: Given that  pkcs11 does not define any combined authenticated mode right now(AFAIK): An attempt with modified ciphertext would fail during the signature verification phase with a different error code (probably a `CKR_SIGNATURE_INVALID`)

Comment: @klook ...we are slowly getting out of scope of the question (and maybe out of scope of this site as well) :)